# JSHint reporting: Unexpected use of '&'

Tags: javascript

My code is like this:

```
if (($scope.option.selectedSubject != null) &
    ($scope.option.selectedCreatedBy != null) &
    ($scope.option.selectedModifiedBy != null)) {

}
```

JSHint is saying:

```
Unexpected use of '&'
```

Can someone explain what I am doing wrong

Comment: You probably want to use `&&`, not `&`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators vs. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

Comment: `&` is bit-wise and operator, your probably want the logical and operator `&&` as @Reeno said.

Answer (score 4):

`&` is a [bitwise `AND` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#.26_%28Bitwise_AND%29). You should use [logical `&&` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_.28&&.29) instead.